# Debugging eslint error in ReactJS: 'List' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, eslint

does anyone know how I can fix this error with my code? 'List' is not defined. eslint(react/jsx-no-undef)

I tried searching the problem and found some solutions related to Python, but I am using JS/React

My code is as follows:

```
         <List>
          {menuOptions.map((item) => (
            <ListItem key={item.text} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={item.text} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        </Box>
      </Drawer>
    </nav>
   );
};


export default Navbar;
```

Disclaimer: most of the code was omitted as it would not let me post this with most of the content being code. I have added the section I am having issues with.

Comment: What are you expecting anyone to do? You're not actually showing where `List` _is_ defined, if anywhere. Please give a [mre].

Comment: If `List` is not defined then it's not defined.  What do you expect it to be defined as and why?

Comment: You're probably missing an `import` but we can't tell you which library you are using for `List`, `ListItem` etc.